# Can't install Visual Studio Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, updates

I'm getting an error when I try to install update 2 to Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Here is a picture of the error.

[image]

Comment: click on **log file** and look here for more details what fails.

Comment: have you checked the log file? Do you see any details?

Comment: Since I really need to use VS right now I postponed the updating. I will let you know when I look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft help suggest to use system file check.
In cmd:

`sfc /scannow`

Maybe some of your system files are corrupted.

Comment: I will try to find some other way to find out what happened but
according to events with Windows Server, I suggest to reinstall whole Visual Studio. Maybe that is the fastest way to resolve.